# How do I interpret the regression output using Artificial Neural Network in R?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, intercept

I'm working on a covid-19 dataset, and I'm interested in using the Artificial Neural Network (ANN) to measure the effect of some independent variables namely: *confirmed cases*, *new cases*, and *total deaths* on the response variable *new deaths*. The attached is the output using `R` Kindly explain how to explain this output, it does not look like the normal linear regression I'm familiar with.

[image].

Comment: It does not look like the normal linear regression because it is not a linear regression. If you want to use neural nets you will have to learn, what they are. It will be really hard to answer your question withouht further indication, what knowledge of neural nets you already have so one can built upon that.

Answer (score 3):

Let's simplify your figure and understand at a more generalized level. This neural network has three layers: Input, Hidden and Output. Each layer has multiple neurons whose activations are determined by:

- Activations of neurons from previous layer
- Weights and bias

[image]

Since this is a fully connected neural network or dense network, there are weights between each neuron between the layers. I have denoted weights by $\theta^{\text{layer 
number}}_{i, j}$, and bias with $b^{\text{layer number}}_{j}$ where $i$ is the neuron from previous layer and $j$ is the current neuron.

Now coming back to the figure you have provided, here are some example of weights and biases using my notation:

- $\theta^{2}_{1, 1}=0.35826$
- $\theta^{2}_{2, 1}=-6.11547$
- $\theta^{3}_{3, 1}=-2.24362$
- $b^{2}_{1}=0.85928$
- $b^{3}_{1}=0.01803$

and so on...

### [image]

Now that we know what each symbol means let's write some equations to get activation of each neuron. Let's assume a $tanh$ activation function.

Second layer activations can be written as:

$$
h_1 = tanh(\theta^{2}_{1, 1}\:x_1 + \theta^{2}_{2, 1}\:x_2 + \theta^{2}_{3, 1}\:x_3 + b^{2}_{1}) = tanh \bigg( \sum_{i=1:3}\theta^{2}_{i, 1}\:x_i + b^{2}_{1} \bigg) \\
h_2 = tanh \bigg( \sum_{i=1:3}\theta^{2}_{i, 2}\:x_i + b^{2}_{2} \bigg) \\
h_3 = tanh \bigg( \sum_{i=1:3}\theta^{3}_{i, 2}\:x_i + b^{2}_{3} \bigg)
$$

And finally the output layer activations can be written as:

$$
y = tanh \bigg( \sum_{i=1:3}\theta^{3}_{i, 1}\:h_i + b^{3}_{1} \bigg)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Black represents the parameter weights.

Blue represents the bias terms (kind of like the intercept in linear regression).

To get the value of a neuron (black circle) towards the right, take the value in the circles to the left, multiply by the weight on the connecting line, and add up those values for all circles pointing towards your circle. We’d typically use a nonlinear activation function, too, such a ReLU, though you have not indicated what you used (if any).

I recommend writing out the full equation of this small neural network, and I hope no one ruins the fun for you before you try to work through it.

**EDIT**

[image]

$g = \text{activation}\big(0.01803 + 2.31748d + 1.00955e - 2.24362f\big)$

Use this to unpack the other six neurons. Then write $g$ in terms of the three predictor variables.

Comment: There are the libraries I used in R:                                                        ```library("neuralnet")```
```library(MASS)```
```library(ggpubr)``` Now, how I write the equation out for interpretation?

Comment: Use the picture to write down the equation on a sheet of paper. No knowledge of R or any other software is necessary for this. (Well...you’ll have to know the activation functions in each neuron, which you’ll get from your code.)

Comment: Using the package `neuralnet` the preset activation function will be logistic, unless other options were chosen.

Comment: This is the equation I come up with from the picture  ```new_death = 0.01803 + 2.3175*confirmed_case + 1.0096*new_case - 2.2436*total_death + error```

Comment: @user2579677 you are missing the effect of the activation functions

Comment: @user2579677 You've missed the activation functions and the multiple layers. Take another shot, making use of all 16 numbers in your picture.

Comment: @Dave Using the activation function, multiple layer, and the 16 numbers, how do I write the equation? Kindly give me an example

Comment: @user2579677 I have given an example in an edit.

Comment: @Dave I can see that you used 2,31748 instead of 0.85928, why?

Comment: $0.85928$ is not connected to $g$.

Comment: @Seyi Have you figured out how to unpack the rest of the equation?

Comment: @Dave Honestly, I can't write the rest of the equations.

Comment: Well I got $g$ by adding up something about the arrows points towards it. Take a shot at writing $d$ by considering the arrows pointing towards it.

Comment: Okay I will do that